# Parrot os not showing text in menu and title

Tags: fonts, parrot-os

Only box are shown in place of text in parrot os after update. Specially in 3rd party apps.

Image of error in font 
[image: Image of error in font]

Comment: I found the problem it was with permission.
- `find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.ttf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;`
- `find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.otf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644 {} \;`
- `sudo fc-cache -r -v`

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Settings` >> `Font` >> Check `Font Management` and make sure You have enough Font for your Os. If you Don't have much then download from `Get New Fonts`